# Exponentiation using while loop in Python

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel

I could not think of any better way to raise to power, except this, but how do I refactor it? I should only use while loop, not for loop, not x**y.

I shall not use pow(x,y)

```
result = 1
base = 3
counter = 1
degree = 4
while counter <= degree:
        result = base * result
        counter += 1
        print("counter %d and the result %d" %(counter, result))
print("result is ", result)
```

Comment: Is this a programming challenge? If it is could you give us the formal requirements? Also do you want a review on the speed?

Comment: ["Refactoring"](http://refactoring.com) has a very specific meaning. You shouldn't use the term as a synonym for "improve".

Comment: You can see some ways of doing what you want here: http://www.programminglogic.com/fast-exponentiation-algorithms/

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is \$O(n)\$ where \$n = \text{degree}\$.
This means the performance of your code is quite poor.
You can make an \$O(\log(n))\$ algorithm by using binary operators on the exponent.

For an explanation of this algorithm, you:

- Have the exponent in a form where you can manipulate it's binary.
- Whilst the exponent isn't empty:

  - If the last (smallest) index of the exponent is 1, times result by the base.
  - Remove the last index of the exponent.
  - Multiply the base by it's self.

Which results in:

```
def pow(base, exp):
    result = 1
    while exp:
        if exp & 1:
            result *= base
        exp >>= 1
        base *= base
    return result
```